# Regex for svg xlink

Tags: javascript, regex

ninjas!

Can anyone help newbie with parsing of svg? I'd like to grab the id from this string

```
... id="aws_7e689ce87fd374d90292c52210118050_use3391" style="fill:#f7a80d;fill-rule:evenodd" ...
```

Seems like i need "All-after-id=-in-quotes"

Thanks!

EDIT:

this is full string:

```
<symbol viewBox="0 0 79 78" id="postcss_856dd3770d70eb5ae0b1a278a42d4963" ><title>postcss-logo-symbol</title><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M15.447 32.623c.106.08.29.132.106.29-.132.184-.29.342-.395.553-.105.185-.184.237-.342.106.21-.343.42-.66.63-.95zM68.342 60.24c0 .078.026.13.026.21.053-.105.053-.158.08-.21h-.106zm0 .236v-.026.026zm-5.368 10.277l-4.58-25.402c-.078-.025-.183-.077-.368-.13.053.105.08.184.106.263.13-.026.184-.026.236-.052 0-.026 0-.052.027-.08l4.58 25.404zm-4.737-31.12c-.026.078-.026.158-.026.237 0-.08 0-.16.028-.238zm.026.526c-.026 0-.026 0-.052-.028v.026c.028.026.028.026.054 0zm-.052.21v-.185c-.077.026-.156.026-.262.053.132.05.264.078.264.13z" fill="#DD3735"/><path d="M78.71 33.967c-.052-1.028-.078-2.056-.184-3.083-.184-1.397-.368-2.82-.684-4.19-.237-1.133-.63-2.214-1.026-3.294-.5-1.265-1-2.556-1.632-3.768-1.026-1.95-2.368-3.69-3.605-5.508-.818-1.16-1.87-2.108-2.66-3.294-.447-.685-1.105-1.264-1.763-1.79-1.053-.845-2.158-1.61-3.263-2.347a32.525 32.525 0 0 0-2.58-1.634c-.71-.397-1.473-.713-2.21-1.056-.842-.395-1.658-.87-2.605-1.054-.238-.05-.448-.13-.685-.21-.605-.21-1.184-.447-1.79-.632-.92-.29-1.815-.632-2.763-.87C50.342 1 49.394.843 48.446.71 47.394.555 46.316.5 45.262.397a26.83 26.83 0 0 0-2.026-.184C42.236.16 41.21.16 40.21.134c-.5-.027-1.026-.08-1.526-.053-.763.026-1.526.105-2.29.21-.736.08-1.473.21-2.183.317-.867.105-1.735.158-2.604.264-.816.106-1.658.264-2.473.396-.29.053-.58.158-.87.21-.63.132-1.288.185-1.92.396-1.13.344-2.263.74-3.368 1.16-1.027.422-2.027.87-3 1.397-1 .552-1.948 1.21-2.895 1.844a45.325 45.325 0 0 0-2.66 1.923c-.84.66-1.63 1.397-2.394 2.135-.42.42-.763.922-1.158 1.396-.657.765-1.315 1.502-1.947 2.293-.524.66-1 1.344-1.5 2.03-.893 1.21-1.656 2.502-2.366 3.794-.29.527-.553 1.054-.816 1.58-.395.79-.816 1.555-1.184 2.372-.264.554-.474 1.16-.632 1.766-.367 1.292-.736 2.61-1.078 3.9-.316 1.16-.395 2.372-.42 3.558-.027 1.054.078 2.082.183 3.136.027.264-.13.58.184.79-.105.29-.026.45.13.5-.182.29.08.476-.024.74-.027.052.08.157.13.236 0 .08-.025.185 0 .264.028.237.133.474.133.738 0 .184.157.395.21.58.026.078 0 .21-.053.263-.158.184-.132.342.105.448.133.342.08.5.054.66.052.236-.027.315 0 .368.21.422.29.896.315 1.37 0 .106.053.212.106.343.026 0 0 .5 0 .5.13-.078.237-.104.368-.157.08.342.158.66.263.95.132.21.132.314.08.34.105.474.157.922.34 1.37 0-.5-.05-1-.13-1.475.368.132.684.263.895.263.027-.08.053-.184.08-.237-.158-.157-.29-.394-.448-.552.053.21 0 .29 0 .37-.105-.054-.237-.107-.368-.16.105-.13.21-.263.368-.42 0-.238-.13-.45-.5-.423.158-.052.316-.13.5-.184.29-.157-.026-.447-.026-.816.026-.447-.237-.895-.316-1.37-.132-.737-.105-1.844-.184-2.582-.158-.132-.29.21-.316.237.08.632.158 1.264.21 1.897-.157-.527-.263-1.107-.394-1.74-.027.185-.053.264-.053.37-.13.13-.026.29.053.474-.184-.08-.395-.052-.395-.052v.738c-.262-.264-.34-.474-.473-.66-.052-.21-.08-.42-.13-.63.05-.133 0-.212 0-.29a15.968 15.968 0 0 1-.08-.634c.026-.026-.026-.42-.026-.42.21.025.343.05.474.05-.263-.34-.08-.552.027-.763.053-.106.237-.13.29-.238.21-.395.553-.71.553-1.212 0-.237.08-.5.105-.738.053-.448.105-.896.13-1.344.054-.58 0-1.16.133-1.713.212-.92.475-1.843.764-2.766.21-.66.448-1.29.71-1.95.395-1.028.764-2.056 1.264-3.03.71-1.424 1.526-2.794 2.316-4.19.5-.87 1.026-1.687 1.58-2.53.525-.817 1.05-1.66 1.657-2.425a21.452 21.452 0 0 1 2.79-2.978c1.053-.948 2.053-1.923 3.184-2.793a32.218 32.218 0 0 1 4.685-3.005c1.343-.71 2.737-1.266 4.132-1.793.895-.342 1.868-.5 2.79-.79 1.052-.343 2.105-.5 3.21-.527.71-.027 1.395-.106 2.105-.185.632-.05 1.263-.104 1.948-.183-.08.105-.106.158-.132.21-.288.422-.604.844-.894 1.265-.237.343-.5.712-.737 1.054-.422.555-.87 1.108-1.264 1.688-.605.87-1.158 1.766-1.79 2.635-.63.843-1.315 1.634-1.973 2.45-.868 1.134-1.684 2.293-2.552 3.426-.79 1.08-1.63 2.11-2.394 3.19-.684.947-1.29 1.95-1.948 2.923-.973 1.45-1.947 2.872-2.92 4.322a271.928 271.928 0 0 1-2.316 3.294c-.053.08-.132.104-.21.157-.21.342-.21.527-.29.685-.21.395-.42.79-.658 1.16-.132.21-.316.394-.474.605-.026-.316.42-.474.21-.87-.13.212-.263.396-.394.607l-.316.63c.105.08.29.133.105.29-.08.133-.158.29-.237.423a.954.954 0 0 0 .29-.264c0 .29-.158.526-.29.763-.105.21-.368.37-.552.527.026.027.21.106.237.132.237-.08.316-.21.343-.132.08-.105.158-.184.184-.263.104-.264.262-.474.525-.58.106-.053.184-.132.263-.21.79-.818 1.606-1.608 2.316-2.478 1.106-1.345 2.106-2.74 3.16-4.11.446-.58.973-1.16 1.446-1.714.078.606.026 1.185 0 1.74-.08.974-.132 1.95-.21 2.95-.027.395 0 .79-.027 1.186 0 .105-.08.184-.08.29 0 .263.08.553.08.817-.08.975-.186 1.923-.265 2.898-.027.21.078.422.13.607-.13 1.422.16 2.925-.078 4.427.184-.29.237-.474.237-.658.025-.158 0-.316 0-.5v-.264c.025-.475.13-.975.078-1.45-.053-.527-.053-1.027.053-1.528.053-.21-.026-.474.106-.738v.395c-.026 1.5.027 3.003-.183 4.505-.027.132.08.37-.21.343-.238.474.052.817-.21 1.08-.054.053.05.29.077.448-.106.317-.106.317.052.343.026.58.08 1.106.105 1.66.42-1 .21-2.03.396-3.058.026.422.053.844.026 1.29 0 .687-.026 1.345-.052 2.03 0 .132-.027.264-.053.396-.08.37-.105.738-.237 1.08-.105.264-.052.66-.052.975v1.003c.105.448-.027.685.052.948-.08.265-.105.344-.08.423l.08.395c.527-.053.29.343.5.553-.158.212-.105.29-.105.397 0 .237-.025.448-.052.685 0 .606-.026 1.212-.026 1.792 0 .08.026.157.026.236 0 .054-.026.74-.026.74.053.078 0 .157-.08.236-.025 0-.104-3.347-.104-3.347h-.395c-.052 1.58.08 3.003-.21 4.48-.316.025-.42.078-.764.078-.816 0-1.632 0-2.448.026-.974 0-1.92.026-2.895.026-.472 0-.972.054-1.446.054-.632 0-1.29-.08-1.92-.08-.975 0-1.922.08-2.896.106-.71.026-1.42.026-2.13.053-.475.025-.95.05-1.422.104-.21.026-.395.105-.658.184-.08 0-.263-.026-.42 0-.265.053-.5.21-.765.264-.395.08-.5.184-.448.58v.263c-.026.052.58-.08.58-.08-.054 0-.08.158-.16.29.212-.08.343-.132.475-.184.395.185.737.08 1.052.16 1.026.262 2.078.37 3.13.473.685.053 1.343.08 2.027.105.973.053 1.947.106 2.92.106.816 0 1.606-.08 2.42-.08 1.13 0 2.264.052 3.395.08.237 0 .5-.028.763-.028h1.92c1.712-.052 3.422-.08 5.133-.13.975-.028 1.975-.08 2.948-.107l3-.08c1.158-.026 2.316-.026 3.448-.05.868 0 1.71-.03 2.58-.055.972-.026 1.972-.105 2.946-.157.527-.027 1.054-.08 1.58-.132.632-.052 1.29-.13 1.92-.157.948-.054 1.922-.08 2.87-.133 1.184-.078 2.368-.183 3.578-.21 1.106-.052 2.237-.026 3.343-.052.974-.027 1.948-.08 2.948-.106l1.66-.08s1.104-.026 1.657-.08c.947-.052 1.894-.157 2.842-.183.604-.027 1.21 0 1.815-.027.973-.026 1.973-.08 2.947-.08.367 0 .762.054 1.236.08-.21.185-.342.29-.5.422.105.026.21.08.316.132a.71.71 0 0 1-.42.13c-.054.133-.107.186-.16.45h.474c-.184 0-.342.237-.526.395-.21-.054-.395 0-.5.29.184.104.158.183.132.29-.316.104-.553.21-.42.552-.107.052-.238.105-.37.184-.13.21-.368.263-.316.553.106.025.21.08.29.104-.132.053-.263.132-.395.184-.473.29-.262.422-.157.554-.08.053-.158.105-.237.132.052.237.13.29.157.29a9.3 9.3 0 0 0-.395.316c-.08.237-.185.342-.29.5-.105.158-.158.37-.29.527-.552.607-.947 1.32-1.657 1.793-.264.185-.5.422-.737.66-.474.447-.895.948-1.395 1.37a29.595 29.595 0 0 1-2.052 1.554 151.56 151.56 0 0 1-2.604 1.792c-.474.315-1 .552-1.5.842-.5.29-.974.554-1.474.843-.316.21-.606.5-.948.66-.868.37-1.79.685-2.684 1.028-.87.37-1.5.685-2.158.922-.605.21-1.237.37-1.868.5-.21.054-.448 0-.685.027-.448.08-.895.186-1.343.238-1.158.158-2.316.264-3.473.422-.685.08-1.343.21-2.027.29-.473.026-.973-.026-1.447-.026-.342 0-.71.08-1.053.027-.552-.08-1.105-.21-1.658-.316-.13-.026-.316-.08-.42-.026-.21.106-.396-.052-.607 0-.13.027-.262-.08-.394-.08-.106-.025-.238.028-.37 0-.29-.078-.552-.183-.87-.157-.313.026-.63-.132-.97-.21-.475-.106-.92-.21-1.396-.317a2.38 2.38 0 0 1-.525-.237c-.685 0-1.133-.026-1.554-.185-.368-.13-.71-.315-1.105-.262-.104.026-.183-.026-.29-.026-.08-.106-.157-.317-.235-.317-.526.027-.842-.42-1.29-.553-.236-.08-.42-.343-.657-.422-.58-.237-1.052-.737-1.71-.816-.21-.027-.42-.132-.658-.21.08.104.13.183.21.262-.763-.37-1.473-.79-2.184-1.186-.104-.026-.183-.13-.262-.184l-.71-.474c-.395.08-.553-.08-.66-.132-.71-.5-1.525-.817-2.21-1.37-.29-.238-.63-.396-.84-.686-.37-.448-.817-.764-1.317-1.027-.394-.21-.762-.448-1.13-.685-.185-.132-.37-.29-.37-.58 0-.185-.078-.37-.315-.264-.105-.158-.21-.342-.342-.395-.316-.13-.526-.37-.763-.58-.237-.21-.42-.5-.71-.605-.527-.21-.843-.658-1.158-1.027-.738-.87-1.396-1.82-2.08-2.74-.053-.08-.158-.133-.237-.212.105.29.237.527.368.79-.262-.105-.446-.29-.604-.474-.027.027 1.815 3.057 1.815 3.057.16.237.29.475.448.712a.813.813 0 0 1-.79-.422c-.236-.42-.5-.684-1.026-.63a4.588 4.588 0 0 1-.13-.58c-.107 0-.185 0-.37-.027.37.58.685 1.08 1.027 1.66-.133-.08-.21-.132-.265-.158.473.5.815 1.133 1.42 1.45.132.605.816.895.974 1.475-.13-.027-.238-.053-.37-.08-.21-.263-.447-.526-.683-.816.052.184.13.342.236.474.316.395.606.79.974 1.133.132.134.316.187.316.424.21.105.29.13.368.13.054.16-.025.397.29.344.21.395.42.395.71.264.343.343.528.37.764.16 0 .13.026.262.026.368.105-.053.08-.132.08-.264.13.105.21.158.262.21.263.37.5.712.868 1.002.5.422.948.87 1.42 1.265.922.765 1.95 1.398 2.975 1.977 1.264.712 2.475 1.476 3.764 2.16 1.552.818 3.21 1.372 4.92 1.767.632.132 1.237.263 1.87.42.55.16 1.104.397 1.657.528.842.185 1.71.343 2.552.5.183.027.37.054.58.08.235.053.524-.053.577.027.132.21.237.104.395.078.184-.053.395-.053.605-.053.737.026 1.447.184 2.184.132.16 0 .396-.133.528.13.236-.105.368-.105.473-.13.028.236 0 .236-.05.262-.054.026-.133.053-.238.132.947.184 1.842.21 2.63 0 1.37.105 2.554-.053 3.686-.448.105.132.184.316.342.053.052-.08.184-.107.29-.133.236-.053.526-.158.736-.08.238.08.317-.13.5-.13.317 0 .606-.027.896-.08.158-.026.316-.105.5-.158a1.285 1.285 0 0 0-.58-.133c.317-.158.606-.29.896-.42-.053.078-.106.183-.21.183h.367c-.08 0-.185.237-.316.395.946-.237 1.814-.448 2.657-.66-.29-.552.315-.367.526-.684-.263.08-.526.158-.79.21.895-.447 1.816-.842 2.71-1.237-.13.158-.29.237-.525.37.158.025.263.025.342.05.42.133.316-.262.447-.5.5 0 .71-.078.947-.158.263-.08.526-.158.79-.263.42-.184.815-.42 1.236-.63.08-.028.21 0 .316 0 .29-.186.394-.344.473-.318.37.053.63-.08.736-.42.184-.133.316-.238.447-.318.578-.316 1.13-.632 1.71-.948.21 0 .316 0 .368-.027.344-.16.66-.342.975-.527a2.258 2.258 0 0 1-.263-.13c.262-.054.34-.08.5-.133.63-.74 1.5-1.24 2.157-1.82.29-.026.29-.105.29-.157.104-.132.21-.29.34-.396.58-.527 1.21-.975 1.737-1.528a37.16 37.16 0 0 0 2.184-2.374c.63-.738 1.264-1.475 1.79-2.292.737-1.133 1.368-2.293 2.026-3.48.474-.842.895-1.685 1.37-2.528.05-.08.157-.185.236-.185.71-.08 1.422-.13 2.106-.21.158-.026.342-.13.5-.21-.08-.132-.132-.29-.21-.422-.106-.16-.264-.29-.37-.45-.104-.13-.183-.29-.262-.447-.08-.13-.158-.236-.237-.37a9.7 9.7 0 0 1-.45-.894c-.026-.08-.08-.21-.052-.29.474-1.027.658-2.134 1.105-3.162.447-1.054.58-2.24.79-3.373.184-1.08.29-2.16.42-3.24.08-.764.185-1.502.21-2.266.16-1.212.106-2.346.08-3.48-.026-1-.08-2.028-.13-3.03zM12.685 66.405c-.184-.21-.342-.448-.526-.658l.08-.08c.287.317.577.633.866.976-.158-.08-.342-.132-.42-.238zm.42.238c.08-.027.16-.027.238-.053.08.132.132.29.21.448-.368-.027-.552-.185-.447-.395zm27.37 10.883v-.08c.5-.052.973-.105 1.473-.157v.077c-.5.08-.973.13-1.473.158zm6.63-.685c-.367.08-.762.133-1.13.186-.132.026-.29.158-.342-.08-.053.027-.106.027-.158.054.13.394.447.078.71.236-.58.08-1.13.132-1.684.21v-.052c.16-.026.343-.053.5-.08v-.078a7.743 7.743 0 0 0-.79-.053c-.077 0-.183.106-.262.132-.105.026-.21.053-.342.053-.447.026-.894.026-1.316.052-.027 0-.08-.026-.106-.026v-.08c1.763-.236 3.5-.473 5.263-.71.027.052.027.105.053.157-.158 0-.263.055-.395.08zm.396-.262c.606-.08 1.16-.132 1.738-.21-1.21.342-1.605.394-1.737.21zM24.58 23.374c.84-1.16 1.71-2.32 2.552-3.505.263-.345.473-.714.736-1.056.08-.106.185-.158.316-.264l-.026-.05c.105-.133.21-.24.263-.344.134-.21.213-.448.318-.685.026-.05.105-.103.105-.103.37.184.37-.21.5-.343.237-.264.474-.553.684-.817.158-.21.316-.395.448-.632.026-.08-.053-.21-.08-.317h-.078c.08-.052.158-.13.237-.184.026 0 .026 0 .052-.026.158-.238.316-.475.474-.686.315-.42.657-.842 1.025-1.21-.052.13-.105.263-.158.368.027 0 .027.027.053.027.316-.422.658-.817.974-1.24-.027-.025-.053-.052-.08-.052-.13.132-.236.264-.368.396-.026-.027-.052-.053-.08-.053.265-.343.528-.685.79-1.08.053.08.106.184.21.395.107-.263.212-.447.29-.632-.078.08-.183.158-.262.238l-.08-.08.474-.71c.5-.712 1-1.45 1.5-2.162.185-.263.42-.474.58-.738.5-1 1.29-1.792 1.894-2.714.132-.184.316-.342.474-.5.13-.16.237-.106.342.026.71.896 1.42 1.818 2.13 2.714.528.66 1.054 1.29 1.554 1.976.605.844 1.184 1.687 1.79 2.53.684.975 1.368 1.95 2.026 2.95 1 1.477 1.947 2.953 2.947 4.428.737 1.08 1.474 2.135 2.184 3.215h-1.344c-1.236-.025-2.5-.13-3.736-.078-1.684.08-3.394.264-5.078.396-2.132.185-4.29.21-6.42.21-.765 0-1.528.107-2.29.16-.922.052-1.817.105-2.738.13-1.08.054-2.13.08-3.21.107-.606.026-1.237 0-1.895 0zm30.183 12.12v.238c-.026 0-.052.027-.105.027-.105-.37-.21-.766-.342-1.135-.263-.765-.553-1.53-1.027-2.214-.528-.737-1-1.5-1.528-2.265-.13-.185-.316-.343-.474-.5-.553-.607-1.106-1.24-1.816-1.687a21.485 21.485 0 0 0-3.29-1.688 7.374 7.374 0 0 1-.92-.474h.63l4.5-.08c.974-.025 1.922-.025 2.895-.078.236 0 .368.08.5.29.236.395.473.79.736 1.186.027.052.08.13.08.21 0 .58 0 1.186.026 1.766.025.606.08 1.186.104 1.792 0 .606-.053 1.238-.026 1.87.027.897.053 1.82.053 2.74zM26.447 26.67c1.237-.053 2.42-.132 3.632-.185.945-.053 1.92-.08 2.866-.132.395-.025.764-.05 1.158 0-.42.212-.842.423-1.21.686-.474.316-.92.737-1.395 1.08-.475.342-.896.764-1.29 1.212-.5.605-1.053 1.132-1.58 1.712-.37.422-.79.817-1.105 1.265-.447.58-.842 1.21-1.263 1.87.132-2.504.29-4.98.184-7.51zm17.185 25.35c-.843.21-1.71.448-2.58.553-.736.106-1.5.08-2.263.08-.686 0-1.344-.026-2.028-.08-.763-.078-1.526-.157-2.263-.5-.633-.29-1.29-.553-1.92-.87-.634-.316-1.265-.684-1.74-1.264-.34-.423-.815-.765-1.236-1.134.08.316.263.58.553.764-.132.158-.316.08-.58-.343-.078.053-.157.08-.21.106.08-.185.158-.37.237-.527-.105-.21-.237-.448-.342-.66-.21-.342-.42-.71-.605-1.053-.053-.08-.053-.158-.105-.237a5.893 5.893 0 0 1-.37-.475c-.21-.315-.394-.657-.657-.974 0 .08.027.158.027.264-.027 0-.053.026-.053.026l-.554-1.344c-.026 0-.026 0-.052.026l.473 1.74c-.026 0-.052.025-.08.025-.077-.104-.156-.21-.21-.34-.052-.212-.21-.212-.34-.133-.08.053-.133.237-.106.316.185.448.395.896.606 1.344.052.158.105.29.184.448.027.053.106.105.106.184.106.21.185.42.316.606.237.316.5.632.737.948.235.316.445.66.656.975.026.053.105.053.13.08.133.395.58.684.896.526.08.606.737.817 1 1.397a11.957 11.957 0 0 1-.763-.343c-.027.026-.027.052-.054.105.316.158.632.316.92.5.265.16.528.317.765.5.316.29.685.45 1.13.554-.024-.08-.05-.107-.05-.107.736.343 1.5.712 2.078 1-2.737.054-5.658.107-8.685.16 0-.5-.026-.975-.026-1.476 0-.21.052-.395.025-.606-.08-1.21-.08-2.424-.237-3.61-.157-1.264-.157-2.503-.13-3.77.025-.683-.027-1.394-.054-2.08 0-.922 0-1.82.028-2.74 0-.132.053-.237.106-.37h.08c.025.054 0 .133.05.16.08.08.212.21.265.184.157-.106.394-.21.447-.37.13-.315.184-.658.184-.974 0-.236.106-.394.21-.553.054-.08.08-.158.133-.263-.105-.08-.21-.132-.342-.237.106-.29.08-.633.475-.79.052-.027.052-.16.08-.238.025-.213.05-.45.078-.66.052.08.08.105.13.157a.42.42 0 0 1 .054-.08c0-.104-.026-.315 0-.315.316-.053.184-.395.342-.553.025-.028-.027-.107-.027-.16 0-.052 0-.13.026-.13.367-.08.315-.475.552-.66.08-.053.105-.13.21-.263.21.368-.158.553-.184.816.446-.263.578-.895.315-1.08.105-.08.21-.184.29-.29.29-.316.604-.606.868-.922.185-.236.29-.526.474-.763.106-.132.316-.237.474-.317.474-.262.92-.552 1.21-1 .053-.053.132-.105.21-.158.08-.053.238-.053.264-.132.027-.052-.052-.184-.105-.263.104-.053.21-.158.42-.264-.08.158-.105.264-.158.37l.13.13c.238-.184.606-.394.843-.552 0-.025-.132-.13-.132-.13-.157.08-.394.21-.63.316.05-.08.05-.132.08-.158.367-.237.735-.474 1.13-.66.92-.42 1.842-.842 2.763-1.237.158-.08.37-.026.553-.026.078 0 .13 0 .21-.026.42-.132.842-.264 1.263-.37.183-.052.393-.078.58-.078.787.025 1.577.025 2.366.078.342.026.658.105.974.21a9.88 9.88 0 0 1 1.184.5c.447.24.868.502 1.29.792.763.5 1.473 1.054 2.236 1.502.737.448 1.316 1.054 1.79 1.74.58.816 1.237 1.554 1.5 2.555l.394 1.74c.08.316.264.632.185 1-.133.66-.238 1.345-.343 2.004-.052.265-.105.53-.078.79.05.82-.265 1.53-.58 2.268-.106.237-.264.475-.395.738a.798.798 0 0 0 .21.106l.237-.474c.027 0 .027 0 .053.027-.132.368-.237.764-.37 1.133-.314.817-.63 1.66-1.025 2.45-.21.448-.58.817-.842 1.24-.262.368-.473.763-.736 1.106-.237.29-.473.58-.79.79-.71.527-1.447 1.054-2.21 1.476-.473.29-1.026.448-1.552.58zm-14.027-1.4l-.026.027c-.055-.026-.134-.052-.186-.105l-.632-.95c-.052-.078-.08-.157-.052-.262.29.448.58.87.895 1.29zm16.37 3.61c1.183-.5 2.157-1.21 3.05-2.028.133-.132.264-.263.422-.37 1.106-.684 1.92-1.633 2.658-2.687.842-1.212 1.395-2.582 2.08-3.873a2.73 2.73 0 0 1 .157-.29c-.053 3.004.29 5.955.684 8.933-2.973.105-6 .21-9.052.316zm26.683-.79c-.026.053-.08.106-.105.16-.027-.054-.027-.133-.053-.24-.158.423-.5.212-.737.212-1.42.027-2.868.027-4.29.027-1.368 0-2.762 0-4.13.024-.448 0-.922.105-1.37.132-1.078.052-2.157.08-3.236.105-.08 0-.158-.13-.29-.236a1.81 1.81 0 0 1-.158.237c-.028-.052-.08-.104-.133-.183-.026.08-.053.158-.08.21H58c-.053-.368-.158-.71-.158-1.08 0-.79.08-1.58.105-2.372.027-.368 0-.71 0-1.054.106.08.185.133.29.21.052-.103.105-.182.158-.26 0 0-.053-.028-.106-.08.05-.027.104-.08.104-.106.026-.08.08-.158.08-.21 0-.185-.054-.343-.08-.5.026 0 .052 0 .08-.028l.157.79h.08c-.106-.183.236-.342-.053-.552-.026-.027.026-.185.026-.264-.08-.157-.13-.315-.21-.526.026-.026.105-.053.184-.08-.105-.052-.184-.104-.263-.13.263-.238.263-.37.026-.633.054-.025.106-.025.106-.05 0-.238 0-.475-.052-.71-.053-.266.08-.58-.316-.74a.79.79 0 0 0 .105.21s-.08.027-.158.08c-.342-.317-.13-.74-.21-1.213.184.053.316.106.447.16-.053-.186-.184-.397-.263-.634h-.107v-1.74c0 .027.184.027.29.054 0-.027.025-.053.025-.08-.08-.105-.185-.21-.29-.342l.053-.053c-.21-.262-.105-.63-.105-.71v-1.845c.264.264-.13.606.264.764v-.263h-.027c-.026-.395-.026-.79-.052-1.186h-.052c-.027.054-.027.08-.054.133h-.052l.158-6.298c.263.342.552.66.736 1 .606 1.108 1.395 2.057 2.132 3.058.632.87 1.21 1.818 1.79 2.714.71 1.08 1.394 2.16 2.105 3.24a81.41 81.41 0 0 0 1.63 2.426c.5.71 1.028 1.396 1.554 2.082.446.606.92 1.212 1.367 1.818.527.738 1.053 1.475 1.58 2.187.262.368.552.737.84 1.106.16.21.396.37.554.5-.025 0-.052 0-.104-.026.08.105.13.184.184.237.29.158.316.316.158.554zM74 46.854v-.185c0 .052.026.13 0 .184zm.895-11.62c-.027 0-.184-.16-.21-.186-.027.08 0 .158-.053.264-.027-.078-.21-.052-.21-.13-.027.368.157.737.13 1.106.08-.053.395-.08.474-.158.027.026.08.052.106.052-.527.396-.395.79-.158 1.24.052.104.21.315.052.526-.052.053.027.21.053.343h.077v.05l-.237.08c-.052-.08-.367-.236-.367-.37v1.346c.263.08.263.448.368.633a.768.768 0 0 0 .107-.21l.027.024c-.027.158-.053.316-.106.475-.052.236-.105.447-.13.684 0 .026.05.08.05.105-.288.66-.13 1.396-.235 2.08-.08.5 0 1.03-.053 1.556-.054.448-.16.922-.264 1.37-.027.08-.08.105-.21.158.052-.316.026-.527-.027-.817-.028 0-.37-.184-.397-.184 0 .37.21.87.29 1.29-.08-.026-.395-.21-.42-.21-.054.316-.054.738-.08 1.08-.027.264-.263.5-.29.79 0 .16.184.264.158.528h.21c0-.526.238-1 .238-1.554h.078c.027.053.106.106.08.132-.053.29-.16.606-.132.896 0 .158.13.316.08.5-.054.16-.08.317-.107.554-.027-.132-.053-.184-.053-.263-.026 0-.263-.027-.29-.027-.026.158.185.316.158.448-.026.026-.052.026-.105.053l-.868-1.266c-.686-1-1.37-2.003-2.054-3.03a6.312 6.312 0 0 1-.475-.79 37.09 37.09 0 0 0-2.71-4.033c-.762-.974-1.37-2.03-2.08-3.055-.656-.975-1.314-1.924-1.972-2.9-.237-.315-.526-.605-.737-.948-.683-1.08-1.29-2.187-1.972-3.267-.58-.897-1.21-1.767-1.816-2.636-.21-.29-.42-.607-.632-.923a.37.37 0 0 1-.052-.182c-.053-.58-.106-1.16-.132-1.713 0-.527.053-1.054.053-1.608v-.474c0-.132.025-.237.025-.37.025-.025.052-.078.078-.104-.763 0-1.553-.028-2.316 0-.5.025-.763-.186-1.105-.555-1-1.133-1.737-2.424-2.605-3.636a162.415 162.415 0 0 0-2.5-3.427c-.685-.922-1.37-1.818-2.053-2.74-.764-1.054-1.5-2.108-2.29-3.162-.948-1.264-1.922-2.53-2.895-3.794-.45-.58-.95-1.133-1.45-1.74.343.054.66.106.975.133l1.264.08c.947.077 1.894.13 2.84.26.79.107 1.58.265 2.396.396 1.738.29 3.448.765 5.106 1.318.974.316 1.92.738 2.87 1.133 2.13.87 4.157 1.924 6.157 3.03.63.343 1 .896 1.472 1.397.685.712 1.37 1.423 2.027 2.16.762.87 1.472 1.766 2.21 2.662.657.79 1.34 1.58 2 2.372.21.237.37.527.552.79.42.633.895 1.24 1.263 1.924.262.502.42 1.082.604 1.635.262.817.526 1.607.79 2.424.183.606.34 1.24.472 1.87.106.423.08.87.21 1.29.16.556 0 1.16.16 1.715.025.053.05.132.078.185.105.104.184.21.026.368-.025.026-.025.13 0 .21.054-.052.08-.105.133-.184 0 .053.025.08.025.105 0 .104-.027.21 0 .315 0 .052.052.13.078.184.053-.054.105-.08.21-.16.237.897.264 1.793.264 2.715 0 .87.157 1.74-.21 2.583.078-.29-.106-.555-.027-.818z" fill="#DD3A0A"/><path d="M58.08 45.482c.025 0 .052.027.052.027l-.027-.03c0-.025 0-.025-.026 0zm4.157 26.036c-.29.21-.58.395-.948.474-.028-.026-.028-.053-.054-.08.29-.184.605-.368.895-.553.027.05.08.104.106.157zM12.895 35.81c.29-.367.58-.736.894-1.105.025.026.235.08.262.105-.29.37-.685.87-.974 1.265-.054-.053-.133-.237-.185-.264zM5.42 48.725c-.21-.448-.42-.923-.63-1.37a.91.91 0 0 1 .236-.106c.29.42.42.92.632 1.37 0 0-.21.105-.237.105zm6.712-12.65c-.158.238-.316.502-.474.74-.026-.028-.316.104-.342.078.158-.237.552-.66.71-.896.027.026.053.053.106.08zM59.422 72.6c.025 0 .025-.026.052-.026.184.026.394.052.605.052-.344.237-.555.21-.66-.026zm-47.24-35.418c.028-.08.08-.158.133-.237.052 0 .13-.027.13-.027.107-.184.107-.316.212-.474-.026-.026-.053-.026-.08-.053-.157.108-.315.24-.473.345.053.052.053.08.053.132-.21-.027-.29.08-.395.368-.026.08-.158.106-.29.21-.026.054-.052.186-.105.317l.027.028c-.053.053-.132.08-.132.08-.158.157-.342.29-.5.447-.026.08-.052.158-.052.237.185-.184.5-.527.737-.738l.027.027c.105-.158.184-.316.29-.474.025.026.025.052.052.08-.08.21-.158.446-.237.657-.055.026-.134.08-.134.053-.105.08-.184.184-.29.263l-.473.316c-.263.237-.526.447-.816.685-.184.29-.368.553-.58.896.317-.08.396.053.37.317.368.052.395-.237.5-.448.026-.054.053-.16.105-.186.237-.21.5-.394.763-.605.053-.053.053-.16.053-.238 0-.026-.133-.026-.212-.053.237-.264.58-.71.816-1 .132-.08.263-.186.263-.265-.026-.29.158-.368.37-.474-.106-.08-.133-.157-.133-.183z" fill="#DD3735"/><path d="M12.71 36.892c-.105.184-.21.342-.315.527l-.158-.08c-.105.605-.474 1.132-.842 1.237.105.053.21.106.29.08.078-.027.13-.16.183-.238l.71-1.028.238-.396-.105-.105zM3.948 48.46c.132 0 .264.026.42.026 0-.105.133-.08.133-.184h.08c0 .132.026.237.026.37h-.552c-.027-.027-.132-.186-.106-.212zm-.21-1.212c-.08-.08-.21-.158-.21-.237-.027-.104.052-.235.13-.367.054.184.08.342.132.527-.027.025-.053.052-.053.078zm.658-1.687c.105.266.21.556.316.82a.798.798 0 0 0-.21.105c-.105-.264-.237-.554-.342-.817a.652.652 0 0 1 .237-.106zm58.58 25.194c.13-.052.288-.08.5-.13-.238.183-.422.315-.58.473-.027-.026-.053-.053-.08-.053.053-.105.106-.184.16-.29zM30.63 15.074c.157-.106.29-.185.447-.29l.052.052c-.16.21-.29.42-.475.685-.026-.183-.026-.29-.053-.42-.026 0 0 0 .027-.026zm7.71 13.333c.237-.106.474-.21.763-.343-.026.158-.026.264-.026.37a.927.927 0 0 0-.264-.054c-.158.027-.448.238-.58.264-.025 0 .106-.21.106-.237zm19.74 22.346c.052.263.552.395.052.658.08.055.157.08.236.134a.2.2 0 0 1-.052.106c-.053.025-.158.078-.21.05-.027 0-.08-.104-.08-.157 0-.237.027-.474.053-.79z" fill="#DD3735"/></g></symbol>
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2729937

Comment: This is barely html! I have a array of formatted strings without complex hierarchy.

Comment: It's XML. Same deal. Just use a XML parser. Quoting the conclusion: `Have you tried using an XML parser instead?` (if you had read the link, you would know)

Comment: Is the string all that is accessible ? Or is the string the attributes of an `svg` element ?

Comment: This seems really naive in my case to grab whole XML parser to solve this trivial task. I do appreciate using proper tools for proper need. But thanks for your time! I appreciate that.

Comment: I have an array of strings for inserting into html, so they are not parseable by cheerio for example.

Comment: Can you show a solid input example, instead of some sparse piece?

Comment: When you ask how to use a regex to grab a string, you have to provide other criteria. Do you want to retrieve all text between quotes in any id, i.e. id="..."? Do you want only id's that begin with "aws_..."? Do want all id's from elements that also have a style attribute? This is critical for getting an answer from others on SO, but it's also critical on your own to figure out how to tackle a problem. In fact, I wonder whether, once you describe your particular use case in more detail, the answer might involve strategies other than regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) :

> You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML. [...] Regular expressions are a tool that is insufficiently sophisticated to understand the constructs employed by HTML. HTML is not a regular language and hence cannot be parsed by regular expressions. Regex queries are not equipped to break down HTML into its meaningful parts.

The conclusion I case was the same as the author:

> Have you tried using an[sic] XML parser instead?

Which is what you can do!

Try this:

```js
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var elem = document.createElement('div');

fragment.appendChild(elem);

elem.innerHTML = '<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50"/></svg>';

alert(elem.getElementsByTagName('circle')[0].getAttribute('cx'));
```

It should alert `60`.

Javascript provides all the tools to mess with this. Just pretend that the string is HTML and you should be fine!

---

**Note**: that code is just an example! Addapting it to work properly is easily done in 5 minutes or less.

Comment: Thanks! That do helped me.

Comment: @walkthroughthecode I feel really flattered that you have accepted my answer, but please, retract the accept mark for at least 2 days or so. Just in case someone shows a better way to do it. There are multiple ways to solve this, and I showed the simplest I could find.

Comment: Not only a good answer but (+1) for the brave _wait and see_ message.

Comment: @sln Thank you! I know this because I tried to do something similar for a syntax highlighter. And I always give that advice. Not every solution solves the problem.